# How to pass hidden field value as parameter to action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do I pass a hidden field value as parameter to action method from kendo grid action method?

```
.Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
 .Events(e => e.Change("UtilitySelected"))
  //.ClientDetailTemplateId("utility-detail")
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .Ajax()
   .ServerOperation(false)
   .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.ISO))
   .Read(operationBuilder => operationBuilder
   .Action("SearchResultJson", "Flash", new { historyType=$("#HistoryName")})
```

Need to pass `$("#HistoryName")` value to the controller

Any way to do that?

Comment: I think you're missing .value on your hidden field reference.
`historyType=$("#HistoryName").value`

Comment: .Action("MarketFlashSearchResultJson", "MarketFlash", new { historyType=$("#HistoryName").val()}), this is also showing error "Unexpected Charector '$' ",

Comment: Is this in a Razor block or script block?